# Use of the word fellow to refer things, not people

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to apply the word *fellow* to a thing, not a person? For example "fellow companies"?

Definitions in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fellow), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fellow) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fellow) all point to *fellow* being applicable only to people.

Comment: Your link to Collins includes the definition "one of a pair; counterpart; mate" with the example "looking for the glove's fellow", so it's not really true that it is applicable only to people.

Answer (score 0):

No, the term "fellow" is typically used to refer to people, not inanimate objects. It's more appropriate to use terms like "related" or "similar" when referring to companies or things.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, Oxford Languages gives, as a subset of the 'person in the same position' definition, 'a thing of the same kind as or otherwise associated with another.'
_"the page has been torn away from its fellows"_ But it's true that it sounds odd to use this of companies.

Comment: @Kate Worth an answer. I'm guessing that the broadened usage doesn't work well with people-groups, irrespective of whether the standalone or attributive usage is in play. A bit like 'That tiger has the heart of a lion': a comparison too close to home and sounding silly or contrived. (// Though [Webster's labels the modifier usage 'adjective', I'm with Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fellow) that it's still a noun.)

Comment: Stop Press. The term 'fellow companies' is [actually defined](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/bop/2005/05-67.pdf) (a stipulative definition by the IMF). This complicates matters And 'fellow enterprises' is used too. // 'Fellow families' can also be found out there, but sounds again faintly ridiculous. But then using 'fellow pages' instead of 'its fellows' is also farcical.

Comment: I'm good with this answer - not least because it specifically says ***typically***. Personally, whereas I'm fine with usages like *ELU's **sister** site ELL*, I think ***ELU's fellow site ELL*** (and OP's cited ***fellow companies***) are anthropomorphisms too far. Not in *every* case - but I certainly think that anyone who feels the need to ask on this site whether it's okay or not should definitely avoid such usages.

Answer (score 0):

A company is often treated as something sentient since it is made up of people. So the phrase "fellow companies" is not unusual. It can refer to companies making the same kind of product or providing the same kind of service; or it can refer to companies that are subsidiaries of the same corporation.

I've never heard a speaker of American English refer to a sock or a glove as a "fellow". We use the word "mate" there.

Comment: So a pair of shoes are sole-mates?

Comment: And a pair of hiking boots are fellow travelers.:-)